# Mark seam on borders only?

Tags: uv, edges

It's quite often that I am selecting a bunch of polygons and want to add seams only on the borders of my selection (rather than on every edge that I have selected) any chance to do that?

Comment: Choose edge selection mode instead of faces.

Comment: Maybe try Select > Select Boundary loop, if that's what do you mean by borders

Comment: @MrZak, that was EXACLTY what I was looking for. U wanna write an answer?